# How to get a position:absolute div on top of relative of another parent

Tags: html, css

Here is my CODE

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second">
    <div class="relative"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cont{
    width:50px;
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.cont .inner{
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}
.fixed{
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    left:50px;background:yellow;
    display:none;
}
.cont .inner:hover .fixed{
    display:block;
}
.second{
    margin-left:50px;
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
}
.second .relative{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    background:blue
}
```

I need to get the yellow DIV on top of the blue DIV, I need the left bar to be fixed and blue bar to be relative, please suggest a solution.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3tffqc/)

thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the absolute div to be on top of your relative div, set `bottom: 100%;`

Comment: Can you make a sketch of the desired result, because I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/uw01vjmL/

I have updated your css a bit, please take a look closely.

```
.cont{
    width:50px;
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    z-index:1
}
.cont .inner{
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}
.fixed{
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    left:50px;background:yellow;
    display:none;
}
.cont .inner:hover .fixed{
    display:block;
}
.second{
    margin-left:50px;
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0
}
.second .relative{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    background:blue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="fixed"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="relative"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    position:relative;
}
.cont {
    width:50px;
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}
.fixed {
    display:none;
}
.inner:hover>.fixed {
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    left:50px;
    background:yellow;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:0px;
}
.second {
    margin-left:50px;
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
}
.second .relative {
    height:500px;
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3tffqc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `z-index` on yellow and blue, if you don't know how to do it search `z-index` on google.